# Select image collection with the most coverage on study area

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, getcoverage

I want to select a Landsat image collection for my area of interest and create a time series for their RGB visualization,
but some image tiles are covered just a small part of the region of interest.
I generate a code that compare areas for each image and just select the images which cover at least 90% of my interested area.

Here is the code,
but the results are not as I expect.
Some images with small coverage are still in selected image collection.

Here is the code:

```
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
// Landat 8 surface reflection data
var L8Coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(geometry).sort('DATE_ACQUIRED')
    .map(applyScaleFactors)
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 0.5)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});

 
print(L8Coll)

var AreaOfInterest = ee.Geometry.Polygon(geometry.coordinates())
print('Polygon area: ', AreaOfInterest.area().divide(1000 * 1000).format('%.3f'));
// to cover most of the rectangle area (90%)
var Threshould=AreaOfInterest.area().multiply(0.9).divide(1000 * 1000).format('%.3f')
var Threshould=ee.Number(Threshould)
print('Threshould',Threshould)
print('Polygon area2',geometry.area({'maxError': 1}).divide(1000 * 1000).format('%.3f'))

var listOfImages = L8Coll.toList(L8Coll.size());
print('List:',listOfImages);

var img1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(3));
Map.addLayer(img1,{},'listOfImages')

var f=ee.Geometry.Polygon(img1)
print('gggg',img1.geometry().area().divide(1000 * 1000).format('%.3f'))
Map.addLayer(img1.geometry())

var ImageArea = function(s) {
  var PC =ee.Image(listOfImages.get(s)).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
//    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13,
  }).values().get(0);
  // We define the operation using the EE API.
  return ee.Number(PC).multiply(0.0009).format('%.1f');
};

var N=L8Coll.size().subtract(1)
print(N)
var S = ee.List.sequence(0, N);
print('S',S)

// Apply your function to each item in the list by using the map() function.
var Areas = S.map(ImageArea)//.format('%.3f');
print('Areas',Areas);  

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

var addTXT = function(n) {
  var l8=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(n))
  var h=Areas.get(n)
//  var t=L8CollLabel.get(n)
  var l8n = l8.copyProperties(l8)
//  .set({'Image_Label': t})
  .set({'Image_Area': h});
  return l8n
};

var L8CollLabeladed=S.map(addTXT)
print('Label Added Landsat 8:',L8CollLabeladed)

var L8CollNew=ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(L8CollLabeladed)
print('L8CollNew',L8CollNew)

print(L8CollNew.first().get('SUN_AZIMUTH').getInfo())

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var L8CollNewFiltered=L8CollNew.filter(ee.Filter.gte('Image_Area', Threshould))
print('L8CollNewFiltered',L8CollNewFiltered)



//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

var compareArea = function(n) {
  var l8=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(n))
  var h=Areas.get(n)
//  var t=L8CollLabel.get(n)
  var l8n = ee.Number(l8.copyProperties(l8)
//  .set({'Image_Label': t})
  .set({'Image_Area': h}));
  return l8n
};

//+++++++++++++++++++

var L8CollNNN = L8CollNew
    .filterMetadata('Image_Area', 'greater_than',Threshould)

print(L8CollNNN)


//+++++++++++++++++++
var N=L8CollNNN.size().subtract(1)

var S = ee.List.sequence(0, N);

var ImageArea1 = function(s) {
  var PC =ee.Image(L8CollNNN.toList(L8CollNNN.size()).get(s)).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
//    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13,
  }).values().get(0);
  // We define the operation using the EE API.
  return ee.Number(PC).multiply(0.0009).format('%.1f');
};
// Apply your function to each item in the list by using the map() function.
var Areas1 = S.map(ImageArea1)//.format('%.3f');
print('Areas1',Areas1);
```

Comment: What is your study area? I applied your approach to `var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-109.031787109375, 42.341450973003425],
          [-109.031787109375, 42.056592054786876],
          [-108.680224609375, 42.056592054786876],
          [-108.680224609375, 42.341450973003425]]], null, false);` and it works as expected.

Comment: coordinates are as here: 0: [29.34145846888171,41.08971838905562]
1: [29.53577914759265,41.08971838905562]
2: [29.53577914759265,41.17427709612364]
3: [29.34145846888171,41.17427709612364]... but when i apply incomplete scenes are apeared in gif by black pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected. I added to it following two functions for retrieving, by another method, all and filtered areas added as property in your collections **L8CollNew** and **L8CollNewFiltered** and, values are as expected compared with the "Threshould" (Threshold?).

```
var allAreas = L8CollNewFiltered_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Image(ele).get('Image_Area');
  
});

print('allAreas', allAreas);

var filterAreas = L8CollNew_lst.map(function (ele) {
  var area = ee.Number.parse(ee.Image(ele).get('Image_Area'));
  return area.gte(ee.Number.parse(Threshould)).multiply(area);
}).removeAll([0]);

print('filterAreas', filterAreas);
```

Complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0fdfb129061c6b5b67cc741ae846887c). After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following image.

[image]

AllAreas and filteredAreas lists have 51 and 40 elements; respectively. Areas in filteredAreas list are higher than Threshould value. Image placed in Map Canvas of GEE has index 0 in **listOfImages** list and, coincidentally, corresponds an incomplete scene.

Comment: to cover most of the rectangle area (90%) i define threshould as this:
var Threshould = AreaOfInterest.area().multiply(0.9).divide(1000 * 1000).format('%.3f');

Comment: so thanks for great idea.. can i get the L8 images rather than just areas (which cover most of the aoi . in fact i want to create a gif image showing the time series of RGB image in that area. in my gif the incomplete scenes are appeared . i try to remove them from gif image

Comment: First comment: Yes, it is OK for areas in km2. I corroborated that. Second comment: Yes, of course. In following link you have the answer: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5aa26177f70ea4f82e261ccc7ccb42c7 . Last function now prints images instead areas.